# Request ajax with html response - Symfony 1.4

Tags: jquery, symfony1, symfony-1.4, symfony-forms

I want to make an ajax request by a method that **returns a html** in **Symfony 1.4**.
All ok but I get an error parse json jquery and nowhere to get a specific treatment or parse json response.

[image: ERROR]
[image: ERROR]

Code In view **consultas.php**  (**template module remision**)

```
<html>
...
<div id="results"> </div>
...
<html>
....
<script>
  function Consultar(){
     var form = $("#remisiones_filter");

     $.ajax({
         url:form.attr("action"),  //actions.class.php => method executeAjaxProcessFilter
         data: form.serialize(),
         contentType: 'text/html',
         type:'GET',
         dataType: 'html',
             success: function(result){
                 $('#results').html(result);
             }
     });

     $('#results').fadeIn();
     return false;
     }

 </script>
```

The php **actions.class.php** (**actions module remision**)

```
public function executeAjaxProcessFilter($request) {
    $this->setLayout(false);   //NO LAYOUT

        $data = "lalala";

        $this->setVar('data',$data);
        $this->setVar('showMatriculas',$showMatriculas);
        /**1**/
      }else
          $this->setVar('data',"error de filtro");

    }
      $this->setVar('data',"Vacio");
  }
```

And the view code html respond **AjaxProcessFilterSuccess.php** (**template module remision**)

```
<div>
<?php print_r($data); ?>
</div>
```

`/**1**/` if respond with return `$this->renderText("lala")`, return is OK and the error does not appear.

Comment: Can you test using the [.load()](http://api.jquery.com/load/) function `function Consultar() {
 var form = $("#remisiones_filter");

 $('#results').load(form.attr("action"), form.serialize())

 $('#results').fadeIn();
 return false;
}`

Comment: Any way your code looks fine to me

Comment: Thanks for replying.
The error remains but found a temporary solution for use with symfony (the problem).
In jQuery parseJSON added exception.

if ( window.JSON && window.JSON.parse ) {        
     try {window.JSON.parse(data);   //Error if data not json!!
        } catch (e) {
     return data;
        }
    return window.JSON.parse( data );
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for your variable $data to be accessible in the template it should be defined as

$this->data = 'lalala'; in the action..

Alternatively if data as sent as a request variable , you can echo $sf_params->get('data');

Comment: That is not associated with my problem.